# API for performing image searches in Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-image-search

I am looking for an API that would allow for an image web search based on query and then be able to extract a direct link to an image.

For example, having a query of:

```
"cute dog"
```

It would be possible to extract a direct link to the image url (along the lines of):

```
https://foo.com/teddy-bear-dogs.jpg
```

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002916/downloading-images-from-google-image-search-using-java) that was resolved using the google Ajax API, but that appears to have been shut down.

If anyone knows of a similar API or alternative solution, any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

As dimo414 pointed out, the google custom search api allows for such functionality. Unfortunately this is limited to 100 free queries a day. If anyone knows of an alternative solution without such a restriction it would be appreciated.

Comment: The question you link to mentions the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), did you try that?

Comment: @dimo414 From what I can tell it appears to have been shut down by google.

Comment: Not the Image API, the Custom Search API.

Comment: @dimo414 I looked into it some more and it seems like it is separate from googles Ajax API and still functional. Thank you for your help, it seems promising.

Comment: You can always web scrape the result from Google image search. Not very clean perhaps, but it should work.